# What was the dithering algorithm used in Sierra and LucasArts games?

Tags: graphics, programming, gaming, software-development, dithering

I am trying to write a program in C# that will re-create the type of dithering used in many of the old Sierra and LucasArts games. I have looked up many different dithering algorithms and none seem to be right. It is very simple. It should produce a grid of alternating colors to mimic 256 colors using only 16. Everything is in a square format.

I have been trying to use the AForge.NET [`AForge.Imaging.ColorReduction`](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/64ca6cd2-d802-c1a2-9547-e8b3aa3a5352.htm) library and I can't get it quite right. I believe the class I want is: `OrderedColorDithering`. I've been using that and tweaking the `ThresholdMatrix`.

There is sort of a tool that does this inside of SCI Companion, but it's too limited for what I want to do.

Here is an example:
[image: Two versions of a screenshot of Sierra’s The Colonel’s Bequest, with the protagonist standing next to a statue in front of the mansion; the original, dithered version and in ScummVM’s undither mode.]

I have implemented the code from ScummVM (this is snipped from inside x,y loop):

```
col = bmp.GetPixel(x, y);

int closeCol = FindNearestColor(VGACols, col);
if ((closeCol & 0xF0) > 0)
{
    closeCol ^= closeCol << 4;
    closeCol = (((x ^ y) & 1) > 0) ? closeCol >> 4 : closeCol & 0x0F;
}

if (closeCol < VGACols.Length)
    outBmp.SetPixel(x, y, VGACols[closeCol]);
```

Using this palette (VGA 256 color mode 13h):

```
VGACols[] = {
    "#000000", "#0000AA", "#00AA00", "#00AAAA", "#AA0000", "#AA00AA",
    "#AA5500", "#AAAAAA", "#555555", "#5555FF", "#55FF55", "#55FFFF",
    "#FF5555", "#FF55FF", "#FFFF55", "#FFFFFF", "#000000", "#101010",
    "#202020", "#353535", "#454545", "#555555", "#656565", "#757575",
    "#8A8A8A", "#9A9A9A", "#AAAAAA", "#BABABA", "#CACACA", "#DFDFDF",
    "#EFEFEF", "#FFFFFF", "#0000FF", "#4100FF", "#8200FF", "#BE00FF",
    "#FF00FF", "#FF00BE", "#FF0082", "#FF0041", "#FF0000", "#FF4100",
    "#FF8200", "#FFBE00", "#FFFF00", "#BEFF00", "#82FF00", "#41FF00",
    "#00FF00", "#00FF41", "#00FF82", "#00FFBE", "#00FFFF", "#00BEFF",
    "#0082FF", "#0041FF", "#8282FF", "#9E82FF", "#BE82FF", "#DF82FF",
    "#FF82FF", "#FF82DF", "#FF82BE", "#FF829E", "#FF8282", "#FF9E82",
    "#FFBE82", "#FFDF82", "#FFFF82", "#DFFF82", "#BEFF82", "#9EFF82",
    "#82FF82", "#82FF9E", "#82FFBE", "#82FFDF", "#82FFFF", "#82DFFF",
    "#82BEFF", "#829EFF", "#BABAFF", "#CABAFF", "#DFBAFF", "#EFBAFF",
    "#FFBAFF", "#FFBAEF", "#FFBADF", "#FFBACA", "#FFBABA", "#FFCABA",
    "#FFDFBA", "#FFEFBA", "#FFFFBA", "#EFFFBA", "#DFFFBA", "#CAFFBA",
    "#BAFFBA", "#BAFFCA", "#BAFFDF", "#BAFFEF", "#BAFFFF", "#BAEFFF",
    "#BADFFF", "#BACAFF", "#000071", "#1C0071", "#390071", "#550071",
    "#710071", "#710055", "#710039", "#71001C", "#710000", "#711C00",
    "#713900", "#715500", "#717100", "#557100", "#397100", "#1C7100",
    "#007100", "#00711C", "#007139", "#007155", "#007171", "#005571",
    "#003971", "#001C71", "#393971", "#453971", "#553971", "#613971",
    "#713971", "#713961", "#713955", "#713945", "#713939", "#714539",
    "#715539", "#716139", "#717139", "#617139", "#557139", "#457139",
    "#397139", "#397145", "#397155", "#397161", "#397171", "#396171",
    "#395571", "#394571", "#515171", "#595171", "#615171", "#695171",
    "#715171", "#715169", "#715161", "#715159", "#715151", "#715951",
    "#716151", "#716951", "#717151", "#697151", "#617151", "#597151",
    "#517151", "#517159", "#517161", "#517169", "#517171", "#516971",
    "#516171", "#515971", "#000041", "#100041", "#200041", "#310041",
    "#410041", "#410031", "#410020", "#410010", "#410000", "#411000",
    "#412000", "#413100", "#414100", "#314100", "#204100", "#104100",
    "#004100", "#004110", "#004120", "#004131", "#004141", "#003141",
    "#002041", "#001041", "#202041", "#282041", "#312041", "#392041",
    "#412041", "#412039", "#412031", "#412028", "#412020", "#412820",
    "#413120", "#413920", "#414120", "#394120", "#314120", "#284120",
    "#204120", "#204128", "#204131", "#204139", "#204141", "#203941",
    "#203141", "#202841", "#2D2D41", "#312D41", "#352D41", "#3D2D41",
    "#412D41", "#412D3D", "#412D35", "#412D31", "#412D2D", "#41312D",
    "#41352D", "#413D2D", "#41412D", "#3D412D", "#35412D", "#31412D",
    "#2D412D", "#2D4131", "#2D4135", "#2D413D", "#2D4141", "#2D3D41",
    "#2D3541", "#2D3141", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000",
    "#000000", "#000000", "#000000", "#000000"
}
```

The dithering style looks correct; it just doesn't use the right colors. I've cross-referenced my palette and it does appear to be the correct 256 color palette. Any additional info would be appreciated.

Comment: Might to add information about the pictures shown? What hardware, are they examples of your work? Also, the question is the way it is formed rather borderline. You might want it to make more about the original games than modern development to keep it on topic.

Comment: If none else works you can try mine [dithering by known color palete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) its very basic so it might create artifacts ...

Comment: Color QuickDraw on early-90s Macintosh did a nice job dithering images down to 16 colors.  It's not a ready-to-go solution, and the source code might not be available, but perhaps that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe my arithmetic is askew, but I make it that there are around 10 billion billion billion of selecting a 16-colour palette from a potential set of 64 — that's 64!/48!. So picking the colour palette is probably the majority of the battle, especially considering how difficult it is to pin down a measure for similarity of colours to allow reasonable vector quantisation (or similar). https://www.compuphase.com/cmetric.htm takes a decent stab at similarity, at least.

Comment: @Tommy IIRC the default EGA/VGA palettes both 16 and 256 color was created for better dithering results ... the idea on pallete is to have each of the primary colors and possibly some shades to limit the number of pixel where the color need to bleed...

Comment: Why do you expect the SCUMM dithering in EGA to match the VGA palette? It was created on EGA, not VGA. It works up from the EGA palette, not down from the VGA palette.

Comment: Oh, OK. I assumed it was working down because I don't understand how you can work up a game that already has only 16 color information. The data would have to be included in the original game, so why the algorithm?

Comment: The artists drew the artwork in the game using dithering. The data in the game, which is decoded using the algorithm implemented in ScummVM, represents the artists’ dithered artwork. See for example [Mark Ferrari’s GDC retrospective](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMcJ1Jvtef0) for some context (this isn’t the best example since he only touches on the Loom artwork very briefly, but it’s the best example I remember off the top of my head).

Comment: See also [this Loom EGA/VGA comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRJD0OrGulU) (which concentrates on the game’s content, but does show some art comparisons — you’ll see the EGA and VGA art were drawn separately, and the VGA art is itself dithered), or [this Monkey Island CGA/EGA/VGA comparison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86O3PxdLrg8). Most if not all LucasArts games have separate graphical resources for different adapters. (And yes, I’m aware I’m talking about LucasArts, not Sierra, so I’ll look for some Sierra examples too.)

Comment: [This comparison video with LSL 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jb7b-N0LJrs) shows the Sierra side of things quite well.

Comment: Admittedly in later Sierra games the situation might be different since they weren’t released as separate EGA/VGA games and used different drivers to handle different output; I’m not sure whether the graphical resources actually changed there.

Comment: @Tommy you are correct if you're talking about permutations, but not combinations.  I would consider palette choice a combination because color similarity matters, not order.  But either way, palettes aren't chosen at random, are they?  Once you have a similarity metric chosen, there's only one closest color to a given pixel, and so there's only one palette to choose from (unless your algorithm is nondeterministic).

Answer (score 10):

SCI games support dithering using any pair of EGA colours; each individual *scene* can use up to four palettes of forty colours (one at a time). When dithering, colours are alternated horizontally and vertically; this means that there are 120 unique dithered variants from a colour perspective, plus the sixteen base colours, but in some cases the order will be important so all 256 values can be useful.

The way these are encoded is as follows, at least [as re-implemented in ScummVM](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm/blob/432fd522d243f0779d2ebf99e8983dbb95cdd175/engines/sci/graphics/screen.cpp#L632):

- the base colours are represented using their standard values, between 0 and 15 inclusive;
- dithered colours, considered as a byte, are exclusive-ored with themselves shifted left by four; the alternating colours are respectively the lower nibble of the result shifted right by four, and the lower nibble of the result.

So for example, colour 215 results in alternating colours 10 and 7.

Comment: So they still take two screen pixel to represent one colour. But the palettes are not made up from a larger 256 colour, but created from what the base colours allow? So more of a reverse creation process when drawing the picture, right?

Comment: Right, they use two pixels for a single colour (or rather, the rendering algorithm determines which of the two colours is appropriate for a given pixel, so you can technically draw a single pixel with a dithered colour — but that’s hair-splitting and you wouldn’t do that when drawing the artwork). I get the impression from looking at presentations by the artists of the time, that they worked up from the constituent colours rather than down from a larger colour space (which would have been hard to work with anyway, at least on PCs before VGA), so yes, more of a reverse creation process.

Comment: I've got to admit I'm confused by the inclusion of the XOR step; this is a digression since it's more like 'why did they do this' than 'what were they doing', but have you any idea what is achieved with that extra bit of processing? Is it something to do with using the same colour information more widely than merely in EGA mode?

Comment: @Tommy I'd see that as an algorithmic way to calculate the two colour numbers - the same coule be archieved by using a look up table I guess.

Comment: @Raffzahn I think I'm still failing to comprehend an important element — I don't presently understand why you wouldn't just say that e.g. the stored colour resolution is 256 colours, in EGA mode 0xab will be output as 0xa next to 0xb in a chequerboard, in VGA colour 0xab will be a blend of EGA colours 0x and 0xb. I suspect you're somehow avoiding the reduction of VGA to 128 colours, hence the "in some cases the order will be important so all 256 values can be useful", but I don't see how storing as 0x(a^b)b rather than 0xab achieves that. Oh well. Not important to the real question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Scumm link. What I've got looks right now except that it's using the wrong colors. My problem is that my 256 color index palette is just incorrect. Is there any list of RGB values for the default VGA color palette. I can not find it. Maybe it can be generated? Thanks!

Comment: @Synaps3 see https://github.com/canidlogic/vgapal ; the README.md describes how the colours can be generated (too long to summarise here), and a C file is provided to print it to `stdout`.

Comment: @tommy I think the reason is so that first 16 values can represent the undithered colours, while still allowing the upper nibble colour to be colour 0 (black). In other words, 0x0*b* means undithered *b* while 0x*bb* means *b* dithered with colour 0.

Answer (score 1):

Preface, this is not an authorative answer, just from rough memory.

---

As far as I remember, they used different techniques. For most parts it was a modified colour scheme:

- All Rendering was based on pixel pairs
- With basic colours they are just that colour
- Diverging colours are made from one pixel of the (closest) base colour and on modifier
- Modifiers where

  - The 'other' colour version (the bright for dim and vice versa)
  - Black
  - Dark Grey
  - Light Grey
  - White
- Position of colour and modifier where swapped between lines

So basically this resulted in a bit less than 74 colours, not 256.

And of course, every background was manually modified to fit best :)