# Amiga game about a detective or a spy in some kind of hotel building

Tags: amiga, identify-this-game

There's a game I played as a young child in the 90s that I am 99% sure was on an Amiga. I've searched high and low and cannot find it, and am beginning to wonder if my memory is not accurate.

I believe the player is a detective (maybe spy?) of some kind, with an inventory, and I remember being in some kind of building that felt like a hotel where there was a locked door and I was never able to find the key to open it.

The hallway of the "hotel" seemed to have wooden panelling I think.

This probably isn't much to go on, but if anyone knows what I am talking about that would be fantastic!

Comment: When I put spy it made me think of James Bond. Looking at "James Bond: The Stealth Affair" again... the hotel part of it does seem to resemble what my description was though it doesn't seem to fit in with my memory but that could have been just remembering it wrongly. 

So quite likely is that one, though don't recognise the other scenes!

Comment: You're allowed to post an answer to your own question, if you think that's it.

Comment: Probably not Mission Elevator

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I'm not 100% convinced it is, but will look again later and see if it's worth adding as an answer.

I remember the entrance hall to the building being quite red.

Answer (score 8):

You might be thinking of *Conspiracy* / *KGB*. You play as a Soviet intelligence agent and explore lots of locations, many of them hotels. It's an exceptionally obtuse game with many ways to get stuck or fail, so I can definitely imagine your main memory of it being stuck.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

*The Colonel’s Bequest*?

(Mild spoilers ahead)

[image: Laura Bow is standing on a staircase to the right side of the mansion’s hallway. On the wooden floor lies a blue carpet with a purple cross-hatch pattern.]

A point-and-click adventure by Sierra in which you play as an amateur detective, Laura Bow visiting her friend Lillian at her grandfather’s mansion, and peep through paintings to discover the other guests’ secrets:

[image: A screenshot of the player eavesdropping on a conversation between Rudy Dijon and Gloria Swansong, the former saying “The old miser probably wouldn’t part with a penny if he could help it. I wonder if Fifi’s getting any of his money, though.”. At the top of the screen, there is a message: “Press the ‘S’ key to skip this scene.”]

There are a number of doors in the game that the player cannot immediately walk through, including [a door to the cellar outside the building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj4Pz.png), and [an attic door locked from the inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oRZl.png).

The above screenshots were taken in ScummVM with undither mode on.  You might have also remembered a version with [characteristic checkerboard dithering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn31x.png) (screenshot taken from [this question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8704/)).

Spy or detective, check; there is a bit of spying and detective work involved.  An Amiga port was released in 1990, check.  The mansion does look somewhat hotel-like, and has wooden floors, so check.  Inventory system, check: you have to collect certain items to solve puzzles and progress through the game.  All in all, this looks like a pretty plausible candidate to me.

Comment: Thank you, I'm fairly sure this isn't the right game but definitely fits the description!

Answer (score 4):

Could this be *Mortville Manor*?

You play the part of a detective investigating an unexplained death in a large manor. Part of the manor does resemble a hotel corridor:

[image: Mortville Manor corridor with doors]

I'm not sure there's much "wood panelling" as such, but there certainly is a period decor:

[image]

And I'm also not sure about a door being locked but it is the kind of game which would have that kind of puzzle!

[Lemon Amiga has a description of the game](https://www.lemonamiga.com/games/details.php?id=764) and there's [a walkthrough video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b06uHzqAJ7Q) which may help say for certain if this is the game you're thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

[Midnight Rescue!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Rescue!) is a game for a much younger target audience than the other stealth-and-sneaking games provided by other answerers, but was one of the few games my elementary school computer lab endorsed. It doesn't involve navigating a hotel, but a school, and I'm not sure if there is so much of an inventory system. Additionally, the game was released in 1989 for DOS/Macintosh with subsequent re-releases in the mid nineties.

[image: Game screenshot from Wikipedia]

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deja_Vu_II:_Lost_in_Las_Vegas also comes to mind.  You start off in a hotel; there are certainly doors that either required finding ways around or through but I feel like you needed to leave the hotel (after finding a way to win at Blackjack) to get to places with locked doors, so I'm guessing this wasn't it, but it was available for Amiga and I played it in early 90's on my Apple II GS.

Answer (score 0):

[Cruise For A Corpse](https://www.mobygames.com/game/cruise-for-a-corpse) perhaps, if the hotel can be a cruise ship.

[image: Inspector]